# Parallel.ForEach problem with synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, parallel.foreach, thread-synchronization

In parallel, I read from the `LIST`(adresses) of devices that I will connect to and from which they will generate an image. If I do it sequentially everything is fine.  If I use a parallel approach, I start to generate images incorrectly - or rather, I name each image according to the name of the device, and this is where the problem arises - the names and images are mixed up.

```
Parallel.ForEach(adresses, new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism=Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 2.0)) },
        device=>
        {   
           _sensor = SensorFactory.ConnectSensor(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(device), Properties.Settings.Default.PortNo));
           sensorName = _sensor.DeviceName.ToString();
           _dataChangeEventHandler = _sensor.Subscribe(DataChangeEventHandler);
           _sensor.Tick(); //requests a connection to the device, another method is called that requests, generates and saves an image to fileshare
         }
       );
```

Does anyone have any advice on where the problem might be and how to solve it or change the concept altogether?

Comment: Since **not a single one of the variables** you are using in the parallel jobs is declared inside the body of the job function, all jobs will operate on the very same `_sensor`, `sensorName` and `_dataChangeEventHandler` variables/fields/properties. One job is assigning its stuff to these variables, then -- in parallel -- another job assigns _its_ own stuff to these variables, etc... And all jobs are using the `_sensor` variable, which of course every job is also setting to its own ConnectSensor instance. It's a goddamn (pardon my Esperanto) race condition bonanza ;-)

Comment: The solution should be relatively simple (caveat: i am not considering your program's overall business logic, which i have no awareness of): Do the opposite of "_not a single one of the variables you are using in the parallel jobs is declared inside the body of the job function_" ;-)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thank you very much. I've spent too much time on it that this hasn't hit me. :D Post this as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution ;) Thanks again

Comment: I would highly advice doing some reading about thread safety before doing anything multi threaded. You really need to be careful when writing any kind multi threaded programs, and most problems are not as easy to spot as this one.